# Image and PDF file upload - Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, pdf, file-upload, upload

Is there any way to upload both Image and Pdf file on the same time (Multiple)
in Laravel?

I can only upload Images but im looking for a way to upload Pdf file which means it can be mix of Image and files.

```php
   'carEvidence' => 'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,doc,pdf,docx,zip|max:10000'

 if ($files = $request->file('carEvidence')) {
            $destinationPath = 'public/image/'; // upload path
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
            $post['carEvidence'] = "$profileImage";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `multiple` on your input file

**Example:**

```
<input type='file' name='filename' multiple/>
```

Then you can click many files in one folder and in your controller you need to use foreach method to get the value

**example**

```
if($request->hasFile('filename')
{
  foreach($request->filename as $filename)
  {
    //your saving code
  }
]
```

Just change the name of the input.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is it able to upload image and pdf at the same time?

Comment: Yes as long as it is on the same folder

Answer (score 2):

**Solved the issue!**

```
 'carEvidence' =>  'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,zip,pdf|max:2048',
```